# Nginx secure link & java

Tags: java, security, nginx

I have a project which I need to stream vids from my server and I'm using nginx to do it, also webapp developed using spring mvc, and tomcat to contain it.

how it works:

java app makes md5 hash link and send it to the client he can make the request, the client make a request with a hashed parameters to the nginx server, the nginx server checks the hashed values and deiced to process to not.

This is the java code to create the hashed link:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String fileName = "bbb.mp4";
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    String monthName = getMonthForInt(month);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    System.out.println("year " +year +", month "+ month +",day " +day + ", hour " +hour +" min "+ min);

    String str = monthName +" "+ day+" "+year+" "+hour+":"+min+":52.454 UTC";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
    Date newDate = df.parse(str);
    long epoch = date.getTime();


    System.out.println(epoch);
    String input =  epoch +"/hls/"+fileName+" enigma";

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(input.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = md.digest();
    String md5Sum = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
    String hash = md5Sum.substring( 0,md5Sum.length() -2);

    String   link = "http://tutorme.ae/hls/"+fileName+"?md5="+hash+"&expires="+epoch;

    System.out.println(link);
}
```

the out put should be like this :

http://tutorme.ae/hls/bbb.mp4?md5=D3U9uEtwHcgyNL3BeyfLsw&expires=1490178647610

so this code works 50%, the other 50% it produce a link slimier to this :

http://tutorme.ae/hls/bbb.mp4?md5=26k/bhvQP6JC1ehR+XmzuA&expires=1490178663810

I'm not sure why it do that and clue will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry for that I just fix it by adding this line of code :

```
         hash = hash.replace("/", "_");
```

in the last line. I don't know the reason in fact it just because the hash in linux command line difference from java. if someone can explain it it would be nice

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a modification of your proposed solution, returning 302 to the client to redirect the download. Base on the examples from [nginx_secure_link module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html) you should replace "+/" by "-_" and delete last 2 chars

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String fileName = "bbb.mp4";

    ZonedDateTime validPeriodTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2024-12-31T00:00:00+01:00[Europe/Paris]");
    long epoch = validPeriodTime.toEpochSecond();

    System.out.println(validPeriodTime);
    System.out.println(epoch);
    String input =  epoch +"/s/"+fileName+" enigma";

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(input.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = md.digest();
    String md5Sum = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(enc);
    String hash = md5Sum.substring( 0,md5Sum.length() -2);
    hash = hash.replace("/", "_").replace("+", "-");

    String link = "http://local.host/s/"+fileName+"?m="+hash+"&e="+epoch;

    System.out.println(link);
}
```

here you can find my nginx config:

```
location /files {
  root /data/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
}

location /s/ {
  root /data/html;

  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

  secure_link $arg_m,$arg_e;
  secure_link_md5 "$arg_e$uri secret";

  if ($secure_link = "") {
    return 403;
  }

  if ($secure_link = "0") {
    return 410;
  }
  rewrite ^/s/(.*)$ /files/$1 break;
}
```